# How to find line of code of address reported by Access Violation Error without using a debugger?

Tags: windows, delphi

How do I find the line of code that is causing the error like this:
Access violation at address 011920F4 in module 'module_name'. Read of address 00000008.

So, how do I find line refereed by the address 011920F4 above?

I can not use debugger since I can not reliably reproduce this error and the error above is what I get from a log file.

I do realize that this might not be possible to find as the address locations change each time you run app but the main point is if it is possible to locate the code that is causing it or get some useful info without use of a debugger.

Much appreciated,
db

Comment: It depends on what OS you're using, but if it's something *nix-y then use [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm).

Comment: Hi Paul and thanks for your reply.  Technologies involved are Delphi, Apache server (which produces log file), all on Windows 7 or higher.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You should configure the system create a crash dump file when the process crashes.  See ["Collecting User-Mode Dumps"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx).  Or grab a drwatson32.exe from an old version of Windows and use it to configure crash dumps.

Comment: Hi Michael and thank you for your reply.  I will take a look at your link.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. Compile your program with a detailed map file. When you get a bug report look the address up in the map file.
2. Use a third party tool like madExcept, EurekaLog or JclDebug. These can produce very detailed crash reports with full stack traces, register captures, disassembly listings, module listings and so on.

Personally, I would heartily recommend option 2. I would not dream of shipping my product without one of these tools.

Comment: Thank you David.  I have never used these tools.  Which one do you recommend.  And if I understand correctly, these tools stay installed with your application once you deploy the application to customers?

Comment: I have experience with madexcept. I recommend it wholeheartedly. Make sure you pay for it if your program is commercial.

Comment: Much appreciated David